# symfony2 if condition on javascript button

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

i have a symfony form that checks if a person already exists in the database by his name and surname.
If it's the case it shows a javascript windows with 3 buttons "add", "modify", "cancel"
if the person is not in the database it persists the data.
What i want to do now is to put an 'if' condition in the same action, so that when the button "add" is clicked, then the data  is persisted anyway. I guess i have to include some javascript in my condition but i don't know how to do this as i'm not familiar whith this language. can anyone show me how to do this, or maybe there is another way... Thanks for your time and answers.

## The form

```
public function createAction(Request $request) {

    $entity = new Invite();

    $id = null;

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $formData = $form->getData();

    $prenom = $form['prenom']->getData();

    $nom = $form['nom']->getData();

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('AcmeProtoBundle:Invite');

        //here the repository query that checks if the person is in the db
        $invites = $repository->findByPrenomAndNom($prenom, $nom, $id);

        //if a person is found with same name and surname
        if ($invites) {
            //in the new.html.twig file the pop up windows appears with the 3 buttons
            return $this->render('AcmeProtoBundle:Invite:new.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $form->createView(),
                        'invite' => $invites
            ));

            //here i would like to put the condition if the "add" button is clicked
            //the data are persisted


        } else {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('invite_show', array(
                                'id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'messages' => $messages,
    );
}
```

## the twig file

```
<div>
        {% if invite is defined %}
            {% for person in invite %}
                <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Attention Doublon">
                    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:30 7px 10px 10;">                  
                        </span> {{person.prenom}} {{person.nom}} ID: {{person.id}} est déjà enregistré</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

## javascript function in the twig file

```
{% block documentReady %}
{% if invite is defined %}
    {% for person in invite %}
        $(function() {
           $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
               resizable: false,
               height: 200,
               width: 500,
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                   "add": function() {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   },

                   "Modify": function() {
                       window.location.href = "{{ path('invite_edit', { 'id': person.id }) }}";
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   },
                   Cancel: function() {
                       window.location.href = "{{ path('invite_search'}}";
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               }
           });
        });
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock documentReady %}
```

Comment: You may one to have a look into https://github.com/showmethecodeteam/showmethecode , where they show several strategies to deal with multiple records in one page. Pay special attention to src/SMTC/MainBundle/Resources/views/Example/Form/new_one_to_many.html.twig where they use a data-prototype HTML built-in Symfony trick to handle collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the "add" button with a route and a variable that you pass to your createAction. Something like this in pseudo-code :

## Controller

```
function CreateAction(Request $request, $isAdding = false) {
    if($form->isValid() || $isAdding) {
        if($isAdding) {
            // Do what you need here
        }
    }
```

## Twig

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Attention Doublon">
    <p> {{person.prenom}} {{person.nom}} ID: {{person.id}} est déjà enregistré</p>
    <a href="your_add_route/is_adding"> Add anyway </a>
</div>
```

## Routing

```
your_add_route:
    pattern: /your_add_route/{is_adding}
    default: createAction
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it works fine! i also had to put the $formData = $form->getData(); in a session.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way for adding in Twig link is:

## Twig

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Attention Doublon">
    <p> {{person.prenom}} {{person.nom}} ID: {{person.id}} est déjà enregistré</p>
    <a href="{{ path('your_add_route', {'is_adding': 'is_adding'}) }}"> Add anyway </a>
```

It will change url if in some day someone will change route for this action